# Setting multiple properties of a component with one function

Tags: sapui5

I have a component in a list in a sapui5 XML view and I want to set multiple properties of that component with one function. E.g. I want to set `text`, `status`, `tooltip` and `icon` of an ObjectStatus together, because the values of those are all different facets of the same data. The issue is that i have to calculate the values to set to those properties from the model with the same relatively time-heavy function. If I write a separate formatter for each of those properties, it has to run the same function for each property. Instead of this I would like to write one function that runs this time-heavy function once and sets a value to all those properties at the same time.

To accomplish this, I have tried creating a sapui5 fragment that could be placed in the list and filled with different information by the createContent function for each instance of that fragment. However I cannot figure out how to do this.

In the view definitions I'm trying to instantiate the fragment like this:

`<core:Fragment fragmentName="QuantificationParameter" type="JS" path="{project>}"/>`

And then I'm trying to set different content to each instance of the fragment:

```
sap.ui.jsfragment("namespace.fragments.QuantificationParameter", { 
    createContent: function(oParentController) {
        //Get the object bound to this list item
        var derived; //Calculate some intermediate information from this object
        return new sap.m.ObjectStatus({
            icon: derived.icon,
            text: derived.text,
            state: derived.state,
            tooltip: derived.tooltip
        });
    }
});
```

While debugging it seems that the createContent function of the fragment is run only once and I cannot figure out any way to access the data that I'm trying to bind to the fragment. Is there any way I can render different content to each instance of the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is called databinding.

But first of all: we do not use JS Fragments, due to the same reason we do not use JS views. Here s a little Blog written on that topic.
https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/01/why-do-we-use-xml-views-rather-js-views-in-sapui5/

Now the databinding part:

I asume, that Fragment will have the same controlls for each instance and you just want the values to change. To do just that you need to create a JSONModel either in your BaseController or component.js. In this Model you store i.e. your Labels text.
Inside your Fragmet you bind that property to the label. Since JSONModels bindingmode is two way by default the Label will change dynamically if you update the model. You can update the model i.e. everytime the user clicks on one of your list items.

Framgmet example:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">

            <f:SimpleForm
                editable="true">
                <f:content>
                    <Input
                        value="{baseModel>/inputA}"
                        type="Text"
                        placeholder="{i18n>placeHolder}"/>
                    <TextArea
                        value="{baseModel>/textA}"/>
                    <TextArea
                        editable="false"
                        value="{baseModel>/textB}"/>
                </f:content>
            </f:SimpleForm>

</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

creation of the model i.e in component.js:

```
var oBaseModel = new JSONModel({
        inputA: "",
        textA: "",
        textB: ""
});
this.setModel(oBaseModel, "baseModel");
```

example for your press lit item funtion: 
(should be in the controller of the view your list is located in)

```
onListPress: function (oEvent) {
    var oLine = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("yourRemoteService").getObject();
    this._oBaseModel.setProperty("/inputA", oLine.ListPropertyA);
    this._oBaseModel.setProperty("/textA", oLine.ListPropertyb);
    this._oBaseModel.setProperty("/textB", oLine.ListPropertyC);
}
```

You should really give that tutorial a go:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. However this is not exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. I have edited the question with additional details.

Comment: if those calculations are so heavyweight, wouldnt it be better to perform them on the backend?

Comment: It's not really a performance issue, more like an issue of principles, plus writing a separate formatter for each property, that all run the same function, is rather tedious. I figured out I can kind of fix this by setting a modelContextChange event handler and setting all the properties I want to set in this one function.

Comment: mmmh the only thing i can think of at the moment is that you could run the code in beforeRendering of the table, you'd had to write the data for every single line in a model, and then bind that model to your list... like that you'd have to run the code just once per line i guess